# Execute a function after the caller function finished in C#

Tags: c#, function, nullreferenceexception

I've a TextBox, on LostFocus event of this i call a function, and here i need to call my function that in some situations have to delete the TextBox, so when the code come back to the LostFocus event, it give me a NullReferenceException.

So how can i do?

Is possible to call my Function only when the LostFocus function finished?

Thanks.

Hi! thanks for your answer.. below you can see a simple of my problem:

```
void senseMessage_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 ...

 MyFunction();

}



void MyFunction()
{
 ...

 senseList.RemoveItem(senseMessage);

 ... add some other items to senseList...

 senseMessage = new StedySoft.SenseSDK.SensePanelTextboxItem();
 senseMessage.Text = "test";
 senseList.AddItem(senseMessage);

}
```

senseList is a List of items, i need to have the senseMessage always at the end of the list.
So when the senseMessage Lost the focus (and is ready for add the text in a new item of the list) i need to delete senseMessage, add the new item, and reAdd the senseMessage.

i hope you can help me..

Comment: Can you paste a bit of your code in your question? We need a little something to go off of here.

Comment: First off, don't delete the TextBox, just make tb.visible = false.

Comment: Can you simply check if your TextBox is null and handle that appropriately?  In my opinion, you are approaching this from the wrong angle.  As other people mention, why "delete" a TextBox when you can reuse it?  This will help the performance of your application.

Comment: I don't know what version of .Net he is using in conjunction with another closed library. Otherwise, there could be other options available. However, it seems that the delegate works as @Alex suggests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
delegate void VoidDelegate();


void senseMessage_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BeginInvoke(new VoidDelegate(MyFunction), new object[]{});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`LostFocus` event is quite low-level and bound closely to WIN32 api. Try to use `Leave` event instead.

If that still won't work, try to use `WindowsFormSynchronizationContext` to delay invoke your function like this:

```
WindowsFormSynchronizationContext.Post(obj => { MyFunction(); }, nil);
```

or something like that. Sorry if the syntax might be inaccurate because I'm running OS X now so I have no VS.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. but no solution. I don't have Leave event, and WindowsFormSynchronizationContext doesn't exist in my netcf application.. :(